# Recommended way to access Spring Context in a JMS Listener

Tags: spring, jms

I am working in a Web Application running in JBoss that utilizes Spring and whenever requests come into the application our web layer gets access to the Spring ApplicationContext via

```
ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request.getSession().getServletContext() );
```

We are adding some JMS Listeners in our application that also need access to ApplicationContext, but
unfortunately the JMS Listeners don't have access to the HttpServletRequest api.

What is the best practice in Spring to get access to the ApplicationContext inside a MessageListener.  Our JMS Listeners are also injected via our spring configuration files.

Comment: Why do you need to access the context?  What is the use case?

Comment: Aaron very basic but good question. I guess I don't I could just inject my needed resources into my listener.  Thanks for you comment and your time.  Not sure what I was thinking when writing the question

Answer (score 2):

If your JMS listeners are themselves Spring beans, as you suggest, then why not just wire the resources needed by the listener directly into it?  The listener is just like any other bean - don't fetch the beans *from* the context, have them injected.

Comment: you are absolutely correct and I am not sure why I did not think about it before hand.